# Select2 takes a long time to load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

When I use select2 in rails and reload this entry appears for 1 second

[image]

Then it goes back to normal like the following picture:

[image]

This is my code and I have tried placing it in css display hidden and visibility true without any success

```
javascript:
  $("#js-customer").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 15,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    
    language: {
      maximumSelected: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customers.limit_max');
      },

      inputTooShort: function (e) {
        return I18n.t('customers.limit_min');
      },

      noResults: function(){
        return I18n.t('customers.not_result_found');
      }
    },
  });
```

and this is my input tags:

```
= f.input :tag_ids, collection: Tag.all, input_html: { class: "js-example-basic-multiple js-example-responsive", multiple: true, id: "js-customer"}, include_blank: false
```

I would greatly appreciate help on this issue.

Comment: you want to use text field and select field combined am I right?

Comment: when does this fire?

Comment: It is the tags collection that causes the list to display for 1 second before disappearing (as in the photo attached to the question) @kaizenx

Comment: What I am looking for is that the list of items does not appear for 1 second @DivyarajSolanki

(shown in attached photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by removing the css styles and the multiple:true from the tag_ids input

```
= f.input :tag_ids, collection: Tag.all, input_html: { id: "js-customer"}, include_blank: false
```

with this it no longer reloads slowly or creates duplicity in the collection

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the select2 was loading before the page was loaded.

Try to add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#js-customer").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 15,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    [...]
```

Comment: In fact it goes worse if I add the code, the item list takes longer to disappear